# Remove/replace a dynamic String in file using unix

Tags: shell, unix

**I have File containing the data like below**
**File Name :- Test.txt**

```
TimeStamp_2017-12-43 09:09:14.0999/-ext-10100/Year/Month/Day
TimeStamp_2000-12-43 07:09:14.0999/-ext-10200/Year/Month/Day
TimeStamp_2015-12-43 06:09:14.0999/-ext-10200/Year/Month/Day
TimeStamp_2010-12-43 05:09:14.0999/-ext-10200/Year/Month/Day
TimeStamp_2011-12-43 04:09:14.0999/-ext-1090/Year/Month/Day
TimeStamp_2018-12-43 03:09:14.0999/-ext-920/Year/Month/Day
TimeStamp_2013-12-43 02:09:14.0999/-ext-1200/Year/Month/Day
TimeStamp_2016-12-43 01:09:14.0999/-ext-02/Year/Month/Day
```

***Here i need to replace or remove  below format in each line***

```
TimeStamp_*/-ext-*
```

**Input line in file(Sampel TimeStamp value and -ext- value is changing every time)

> TimeStamp_2017-12-43 09:09:14.0999/-ext-10100/Year/Month/Day

```
Ouput Line after remove or replace
```

**Year/Month/Day**

Can any one help on this Question

Answer (score 0):

Simply with **`sed**`:

```
sed 's@.*-ext-[^/]*/@@' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below `sed` command, it will work for you. How will it work? First it will find the pattern `TimeStamp_.*-ext-.*` (here you need to add dot `.` with `*` to inform `sed` command that you are using `*` as wild card character) and replace with a blank line and second expression `/^\s*$/d` will search for blank line and remove it and finally you will get your required output. Every expression is separated with `;` in `sed` command.

```
sed -e 's/TimeStamp_.*-ext-.*//;/^\s*$/d' Test.txt > tmp.txt
mv tmp.txt Test.txt
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you so much Pritam for helping on this Question.

Answer (score 0):

When you wat to keep everything after the second slash, use

```
cut -d"/" -f3- Test.txt
```